# Nothing shown in comboBox c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want the MySql data to be shown in comboBox. It all worked fine yesterday when I was doing it, but today I wanted to improve the program. I saw the data doesn't get shown in the comboBox, but it all worked fine yesterday. Please help me out and the MySql server is running database is correct

the code:

```
public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Fillcombo();
    }

    void Fillcombo()
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM filmi.film ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString("film");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step thru the program with Debugging. Put a break point and check to see what happens line by line. I'm pretty sure `myReader.GetString("film");` is returning nothing...

Comment: And please use using blocks.

Comment: do you have the column `film` in your table `filmi.film`?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi ye i do

Comment: it worked all fine yestarday :/

Comment: for just clarification i could not see password from your connection string, are you providing it(root)?

Comment: no its no password my password is empty

Comment: @user3389744:are you sure your table `film` has rows? might be deleted by someone , could you please check it?

Comment: Set break point on `comboBox1.items.Add(sName);` and check if sName is `null` or `""`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi i checked its still there :/

Comment: is there anyway something could change at computer restart? cuz i run it after i turnd off my pc yestarday it worked today i turn on pc run the program and the combo box didnt work

Comment: @user3389744: i have analysed your problem, im sure that you are calling some other constructor which does not have the `Fillcombo();` statement, check my answer beow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From Your comments:

I Suspect that you are not calling the `Form3()` default constructor but you are calling some other `Form3(string somethig)` constructor which takes 1 or more arguments.

Please check from where you are invoking this `Form3` and wether you are calling default constructor or some other constructor.

if you are calling some other constructor which accepts arguments add `Fillcombo();` statement there also.

Comment: i dont get it :/ is it possible u could check that on my pc?

Comment: what do you mean with ping you?